# how to minimize this logic (or-gate CNF)?

Tags: algorithm, logic, circuit

I'm writing down the truth table for the OR-gate in a circuit satisfiability problem (this has to do with reduction of the 3-satisfiability problem).

I have:

```
a  b  c    c = (a OR b)
1  1  1    1
1  1  0    0
1  0  1    1
1  0  0    0
0  1  1    1
0  1  0    0
0  0  1    0
0  0  0    1
```

So if I take the rows with 0 in the column c = (a OR b), and negate the a,b,c then i get the four clauses:

```
!a AND !b AND c
a AND !b AND !c
a AND !b and c
a AND b AND !c
```

I'm trying to minimize these clauses. I know that the right answer is:

```
c OR !a
c OR !b
c OR !a or !b
```

How do I minimize those four clauses? is there a program online? I used wolfram, but it didn't output the right answer, so if anyone has a second to help that would be amazing

Comment: I vaguely remember this from college... Take a look at [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: Your third conjunctive clause seems to be wrong -- it should be "!a AND b AND !c".

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that the last column is almost the same as `c` column except two last rows.
And for the two last rows it have values from column `c` swapped. So we can write as:

```
if (a ∨ b) then c else ¬c
```

`if c then t else f` can be represented as CNF `(c ∨ t) ∧ (¬c ∨ f)` so the formula above will  look like:

```
(a ∨ b ∨ ¬c) ∧ (¬(a ∨ b) ∨ c)
= (a ∨ b ∨ ¬c) ∧ ((¬a ∧ ¬b) ∨ c)
= (a ∨ b ∨ ¬c) ∧ (¬a ∨ c) ∧ (¬b ∨ c)
```

And the last one is exactly what you want.